# jquery does not work, when performed ajax request to reload a div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

I have read many solutions, and I read that I should use the "on" jquery.but it does not work me.

I have a field that normally works the calendar picker. I have a button, when I click on this, a div is recharged and a field with the same id for the calendar picker function added.
But apparently the button is not working. on the calendar picker it does not work either.
I want to have the button and the text field within the div and make the Ajax request to continue operating the calendar picker.

test.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head> 
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
            <title>
            </title>  
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css'/>   <!--Carga los estilos de jquery-->
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){

                        $("#generateDiv").click(function() {

                            $.ajax({
                                  type:"POST",
                                  url: "ajax.php"

                            }).done(function(data) {

                                $("#divReloaded").html(data);
                            });

                        })

                        $( "#fecha" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
                    })
        </script>

        <!--Fin enlaces-->
        </head> 
        <body>
            <div id='divReloaded'>
                <input type='text' id='fecha'>
                <input type='button' id='generateDiv'  value='button' >

            </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
 echo "not works jquery :(<br>";
 echo "<input type='text' id='fecha'>";
 echo "<input type='button' id='generateDiv' value='button' >;"
?>
```

Comment: Are you seeing any feedback in the console?

Comment: try to usе on('click', element, callback) instead of click(callback)

Comment: @AdamJeffers thanks for answering. I have no errors in the console.

Comment: console.log(data) and post for us in your done function

Comment: @bmalets                 `$("#generateDiv").on("click", "#fecha #generateDiv", function() { `  not works the button

Comment: @Brant console.log(data) = not works jquery :(<br><input type='text' id='fecha'><input type='button' id='generateDiv' value='button' >;

Comment: This looks like a common event delegation issue... try `$("#divReloaded").on('click', '#generateDiv', function() { // do your stuff })`

Comment: @AdamJeffers always works the button! but no the calendar..       $("#divReloaded").on('click', '#generateDiv' , function() {}

Comment: You said in your post that the button AND the calendar wasn't working! Has my suggestion fixed the issue with the button or are you now saying that the button always worked? I'm confused! This is getting too long for comments now so will add an answer depending on your response

Comment: @AdamJeffers Sorry, I do not speak good English. maybe there was a confusion. It has always worked in "test.php" calendar and the button. ajax call but does not work either.

Comment: @AdamJeffers With this code `$("#divReloaded").on('click', '#generateDiv' , function() {}` now button always works. but does not the calendar in the request ajax.

Comment: @AdamJeffers I need after the ajax call, works the calendar picker and also works the  button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following discussion in comments, see below answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Adopted event delegation to make sure dynamically added elements are bound to
    $("#divReloaded").on('click', '#generateDiv', function() {

        $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: "ajax.php"

        }).done(function(data) {

            $("#divReloaded").html(data);

            // Moved this inside the done() function so datepicker is re-applied
            $("#divReloaded").find("#fecha").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

## fetcha does not exist at the time the DOM loads so it has no listener assigned.

You might want to try using an observer to watch for DOM changes, and then add a click handler to the #fetcha ID once it exists.

Learn about the observer pattern here:
https://carldanley.com/js-observer-pattern/

Comment: It's wrapped in a document.ready call meaning it should be in the dom the first time when this goes down.

Comment: Look at the ajax.php portion of the script. The IDs on the fields do not exist in the dom until AFTER the page is loaded and the user clicks on the first button. After the button is clicked, nothing works because there is no listener on the elements defined in ajax.php

The button that exists on DOM load is the only thing on the page that has a listener assigned.

Comment: @DannyGibas Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: @DannyGibas you can help? I do not understand how to fix my code. I need the button and the calendar picker works.

Comment: A simple way to do it without an Observer is to utilize the callback on your AJAX query.

`.done(function(data) {`

`$("#divReloaded").html(data);`
`$( "#generateDiv" ).on( "click", function() {`
  `do whatever......`
`});`
        `});`

This way a listener is added to the new div instance after the AJAX load is complete.

Answer (score -1):

You must re-tailor your own code to make this work.

1 - First of all you don't have any style sheet in your header but only jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css

2 - Second you are not explaining if the date picker is included in your custom jquery-ui, if not you ust install a plugin for it.

3 - You need to put the javascript which contains the ajax call just before the body tag on the end of the page.. In this way you allow it to found the input by the 'fecha' id;

4 - I also advise you to use bootstrap.css for your style sheet and bootstrap.js.

I don't understand what your ajax.php is doing.

Your code as now is, can not do what you want.

Try first to take the above mentioned steps code your ajax.php and re-post an other question. We are glad to help you but you fist need to help your self. Let us know.